# Getting [: too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I keep getting a runtime error saying [: too many arguments.

Here's my code

Variables

```
mem_list=/root/Desktop/Dan/List/list.txt
word=[user inputs some word]
```

The code:

```
if [ -f "$mem_list" -a grep "$word" "$mem_list" ]
then
    echo "word already exists in list"
else
    echo "word does not exist yet"
fi
```

Keep getting [: too many arguments!!

Help me kindly please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a command, use `cmd`. Not `[ cmd ]`.

`/bin/[` is just another command like `grep`, and `if` will check the exit status:

```
if [ -f "$mem_list" ] && grep -q "$word" "$mem_list"
then
    echo "word already exists in list"
else
    echo "word does not exist yet"
fi
```